# Are $\cap A_n$ and $\cup A_n$ standard notations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I read several papers using the object: $\cup A_n$.

After thinking for days I fig out that they mean: $\lim_{m\to\infty}\cup_1^m A_n$ or $\cup_1^{\infty} A_n$.

Are those standard notation such that the authors did not even bother to define it?

Comment: That limit you've written is not necessarily well defined. Anyways usually something like $\bigcup A_n$ or $\bigcup_n A_n$ just means the union the $A_n$ over all $n$, where the set $n$ lies in is implicit, but usually very clear

Comment: Ok I am writing a paper using similar notation. I am choosing between $\bigcup A_n$, $\bigcup_\infty A_n$, and $\bigcup_n A_n$. Which one cause least confusion for the general audience?

Comment: The least amount of possible confusion? If you have an indexed family of set $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$, then just write $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ and there really is no possible confusion. So for example if you have a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, I'd say write $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$. If you for some reason don't want to do that, then out of the ones you listed $\bigcup_n A_n$ is probably the least ambiguous one (and the one with the subscript of $\infty$ would be by far the most ambiguous).

Comment: @Lorago Thanks a lot for your helps! By saying "the limit is not necessarily well-defined", do you mean that the limit does not equal to $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n$? Do we have an example?

Comment: Well how would you define the limit?

Comment: @Lorago In my limited knowledge the only way of defining that limit is $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$. I wonder if there is a second way.

Comment: Note that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ is used as union of the family of sets $\mathcal{A}$. So that if for example, $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, ...\}$ then $\bigcup \mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, but $\bigcup A_n$ could be confused for something else than $\bigcup_n A_n$.